# shortest path geometry transformation problem

Tags: geometry

[image]The problem goes:
A girl is standing at the beginning of a 12 meter long fence with flowers, and is 6 meters (perpendicularly) away from it. A boy is standing at the end of the fence, 3 meters (perpendicularly) away from it.

What is the shortest path the girl has to take, to get to the fence and pluck a flower, then go to the boy and hand it over to him?

I'm supposed to solve this without using derivatives. It's under the chapter called "geometric transformations", so I'm supposed to use a certain type of transformation (rotation, reflection...) to solve it. I know how to do it with derivatives, but I'm lost without them.

I noticed that the solution I got with derivatives gives me 2 similar triangles, one of them being 2 times bigger for each side. Why would using similar triangles give me the shortest path?

Comment: Can you maybe add a drawing? I imagine a 12 meter long fence as a line. How can the girl stand away perpendicularly away from it at the beginning? Does the fence have the flowers on it?

Comment: Sorry about my poor description... Forget the girl, I've uploaded the drawing. I have to find the smallest sum of the hypotenuses, and I cannot use derivatives since this is a problem from my 2nd year in highschool (I'm relearing math). When I solved it with derivatives I got 2 similar triangles, so I'm wondering if that's always the case, and if it is, why is that so? And if it's not, what other method can I use?

Comment: With derivatives you mean you let $x$ be the point where the girl picks up the flower and then optimize the distance using the first derivative of the total distance depending on $x$?

Comment: Haven't you seen the **classical trick** which is to transform your issue into the similar issue where the boy B is in the symmetric spot B' with respect to the fence ? In this way, the shortest path is evidently GB'. Just a drawback : the girl has to jump over the fence ...

Comment: With derivatives I divide the 12 meter fence to x (to the right of the point where she picks up the flower) and 12-x (to the left). I set the hypotenuses to a and b, and calculate a+b with the Pythagorean theorem. I then take the first derivative of the sum a+b and set it equal to 0 to find the critical points, and take the x value where the critical point is a minimum of the function. In that case I get x = 4 and a+b = 15, which is the correct answer according to the solution in the texbook.

Comment: The thing is that this problem is in a 2nd grade textbook, and we had no idea what derivatives were at the time

Comment: Consistent with the comment of @JeanMarie, **light** always chooses the shortest path.  Pretend that the fence is a **mirror**, and that the girl is shining a flashlight onto the mirror, and *aiming* for the *image of the boy*.

Comment: Thanks Jean Marie, that's the solution haha. All clear now